# Retrieve date from Mysql inverted

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing dates in my database like this: 2014-09-08. I want to retrieve them to my php script inverted: 08-09-2014. They are DATE.

How can I do this in my query? Or even in php if not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using MySQL, you can use `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Using PHP, you can do this way:

```
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["date"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the date from the database and use [***date() function***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format date. [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/189944) The demo outputs `08-09-2014`.

```
<?php

$date = $row["date"];   //if value of date is 2014-09-08

echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); //outputs 08-09-2014

?>
```